# AngularJS: How to retrieve Foursquare API array data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, foursquare

I'm trying to retrieve venues list using angularjs. Using console.log(data), I can see the the angularJS successully calling the foursquare api.

But how do I parse through each id element in the data. For example, I want to get venue name, venue contact and other details, how can I use this in ng-repeat tag.

```
var results = this;
$http.get("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=SECRET_KEY&v=20130815&ll=17.416471,78.438247&query=coffee")
.success(function(data){
    results = data;
    console.log(results);        
})
```

Check this link for sample json data: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore.html#req=venues/trending%3Fll%3D40.7,-74

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=SECRET_KEY&v=20130815&ll=17.416471,78.438247&query=coffee?callback=JSON_CALLBACK;

$http.jsonp(url)
    .success(function(data){
        console.log(data.found);
    });
```

since you are making request to another domain, have to use JSONP. and append callback at the end of your url.

It works!!

Comment: I'm getting the following error.
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" 
When I checked the response it was like this
{"meta":{"code":200},"response":{"venues":[]}}

Do I need to give any additional parameters to the jsonp call?

Comment: Can you please give a fiddle link? It will be easy to debug. Thx